# Microsoft Outlook 2010 does not show upcoming appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I see the message, "No upcoming appointments."  However, there are upcoming appointments (even some for today) and they don't show unless I click on the calendar.

Comment: Are they in your default calendar or are they in an alternate calendar? Also make sure when you right click `to do bar -> options -> show appointments` That `show all events` and `show details of private events` is checked

Comment: Sorry, but you are dealing with a novice, now can I tell if it is a default calendar or an alternate calendar?

Comment: When you go to the calendar on the left is a listing under `My Calendars` do you have only one there or are there more?

Comment: Raystafarian, those are all checked.  It was working fine until I clicked on File -> calendar -> Add Holidays.

Comment: I see that I have two calendars.

Comment: Are the upcoming events on the top calendar or the bottom calendar? The top calendar should be your default calendar.

Comment: checking and unchecking the two different calendars doesn't make any difference.  It still shows "No upcoming appointments."

Comment: The upcoming appointments are on the bottom calendar.

Comment: Try Right clicking the `to do bar` and deselecting appointments. Then right click again and select appointments. If that doesn't work try to right click the `to do bar -> options -> number of month rows` and change the number of months to display and then change it back. We're trying to reset the view. Have you restarted outlook?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know where the "to do bar" is.  Also, I am fine moving this to chat it that is possible for a newbie.

Comment: I found the "to do bar" and tried everything you suggested and still not working.  Yes, I have restarted Outlook numerous times.

Comment: BTW - I moved the calendar so that it is the top calendar and that made no difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you fixed this problem, please post the solution, Thank you.

Some notes before I explain my fix. I have four accounts setup with Outlook 2010: personal, college, public/internships/work, and work. I have multiple appointments set up with my work account. The work and college accounts are setup via Microsoft Exchange Server. The other two accounts are setup through POP3/SMPT. I currently have my personal account setup as the default account.

I currently have the same problem, here's my fix:

1. Click the **File** menu drop-down in the upper left.
2. Click the **Info** tab on the left pane
3. Click the **Account Settings** button
4. Click **Account Settings...**
5. Click on the **E-mail** tab on the left
6. Click on the account with the appointments, in my case my work account
7. Click, **"Set as Default"**, below the tab options
8. Click on the **Data Files** tab
9. Click on the account with the appointments, in my case my work account
10. Click, **"Set as Default"**, below the tab options
11. Click **Yes**
12. Click **Close**
13. Close out of Outlook 2010 by clicking the "X" button in the upper right
14. Re-open Outlook 2010
15. Verify that the appropriate appointments are shown on the right

Comment: In my case it was required to **Set as Default** on **Data Files** tab (_there was already one e-mail account and it was default_).

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2007/2010 you can try this: (worked for me)

- Close Outlook if it is open.
- Start Outlook from the command line with the `/resettodobar` switch as described [here](http://www.outlook-tips.net/how-to/using-outlook-command-lines).
- Close Outlook.
- Start Outlook normally again.
- Go to View/To-Do Bar/Options to reconfigure your to-do bar (how many months and/or how many appointments to display.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried the Outlook /switch procedure described in the previous post by mousio, but the various file paths to get to Outlook kept failing.

Success came by doing an adapted version of mousio's last step, namely:

Go to View > Month > High Detail

I'm using Outlook 2010.